# HttpUrlConnection gerResponseCode giving connection reset exception

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, socketexception, http-response-codes, connection-reset

When i try to hit con.getResponseCode() i get connection reset exception but while hitting the same url in web browser it returns the response correctly but from my code the response is not returned. Please help me to check this.

```
This is the code:-

private HttpURLConnection con;
private String directory;

public MIMESender(String url_path,String provider,String user,String password) throws Exception {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    URL url = new URL(url_path);
    System.out.println("Url Path=====" + url_path);
    con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    con.setRequestMethod("POST");

    con.setDoOutput(true);

    con.setRequestProperty("X-XIAM-ContentProvider",provider);
    con.setRequestProperty("X-XIAM-ContentUsername",user);
    con.setRequestProperty("X-XIAM-ContentPassword",password);
    //System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
    //System.out.println("Keep Alive=========" + System.getProperty("http.keepAlive"));
}

public void setContentType(String type) throws IOException
{
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",type);
}

public static MimeBodyPart createXMLPart(String xml) throws MessagingException
{
    ByteArrayDataSource fileData = new ByteArrayDataSource(xml.getBytes(),"text/xml");
    DataHandler fileDataHandler = new DataHandler(fileData);
    MimeBodyPart body = new MimeBodyPart();
    body.setDataHandler(fileDataHandler);
    body.setHeader("Content-Type",fileData.getContentType());
    return body;
}

public static MimeBodyPart createBodyPart(String filename) throws MessagingException
{
    File file = new File(filename);
    return createBodyPart(file);
}

public static MimeBodyPart createBodyPart(File file) throws MessagingException
{
    FileDataSource fileData = new FileDataSource(file);
    DataHandler fileDataHandler = new DataHandler(fileData);
    MimeBodyPart body = new MimeBodyPart();
    body.setDataHandler(fileDataHandler);
    body.setHeader("Content-Type",fileData.getContentType());
    if(!fileData.getContentType().startsWith("text"))
        body.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding","base64");
    else body.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding","7bit");
    body.setContentID(file.getName());
    body.setHeader("Content-Location",file.getName());
    body.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+file.getName());      
    return body;
}

public static MimeBodyPart createBodyPart(String location,File file) throws MessagingException
{
    FileDataSource fileData = new FileDataSource(file);
    DataHandler fileDataHandler = new DataHandler(fileData);
    MimeBodyPart body = new MimeBodyPart();
    body.setDataHandler(fileDataHandler);
    body.setHeader("Content-Type",fileData.getContentType());
    if(!fileData.getContentType().startsWith("text"))
        body.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding","base64");
    body.setContentID(file.getName());
    body.setHeader("Content-Location",location);
    body.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+file.getName());   
    return body;
}

public String sendItem(String xml,String location,String filename) throws MessagingException,IOException
{

    String response = null;
    MimeMultipart mime = new MimeMultipart();
    mime.setSubType("related");                     
    String type = mime.getContentType();
    setContentType(type);

    mime.addBodyPart(MIMESender.createXMLPart(xml));

    if(!filename.equals(""))
    {   
        File file = new File(filename);
        mime.addBodyPart(MIMESender.createBodyPart(location,file));
    }
    response = submit(mime);
    return response;
}

public String send(String xml,String location,String filename) throws MessagingException,IOException
{
    String response = null;
    response = send(xml,location,new File(filename));
    return response;
}

public String send(String xml,String location,File file) throws MessagingException,IOException
{
    String response = null;
    File[] files = new File[1];
    files[0] = file;
    response = send(xml,location,files);
    return response; 
}

public String send(String xml,String location,File[] files) throws MessagingException,IOException
{
    String response = null;

    try
    {

    MimeMultipart mime = new MimeMultipart();
    mime.setSubType("related");         
    String type = mime.getContentType();
    setContentType(type);

    mime.addBodyPart(MIMESender.createXMLPart(xml));

    MimeMultipart mime_mix = new MimeMultipart();
    mime_mix.setSubType("mixed");
    for(int i=0;i<files.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("files : " + files[i]);
        mime_mix.addBodyPart(MIMESender.createBodyPart(files[i]));
    }

    MimeBodyPart body_mix = new MimeBodyPart();
    body_mix.setContent(mime_mix);
    body_mix.setHeader("Content-Type",mime_mix.getContentType());
    body_mix.setHeader("Content-Location",location);
    mime.addBodyPart(body_mix);

    response = submit(mime);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}

public String send(String xml,String location,File[] files,String preloc,String preview) throws MessagingException,IOException
{
    String response = null;
    MimeMultipart mime = new MimeMultipart();
    mime.setSubType("related");         
    String type = mime.getContentType();
    setContentType(type);

    mime.addBodyPart(MIMESender.createXMLPart(xml));

    if(location!=null)
    {
        System.out.println("Inside Location not equals to null");
        MimeMultipart mime_mix = new MimeMultipart();
        mime_mix.setSubType("mixed");
        for(int i=0;i<files.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(files[i].getAbsolutePath() + " - " + files[i].exists());
            mime_mix.addBodyPart(MIMESender.createBodyPart(files[i]));
        }

        MimeBodyPart body_mix = new MimeBodyPart();
        body_mix.setContent(mime_mix);
        body_mix.setHeader("Content-Type",mime_mix.getContentType());
        body_mix.setHeader("Content-Location",location);
        mime.addBodyPart(body_mix);
    }

    if(preloc!=null){
    File file = new File(preview);
    mime.addBodyPart(MIMESender.createBodyPart(preloc,file));
    }
    response = submit(mime);
    return response;
}

public String submit(MimeMultipart mime) throws IOException, MessagingException
{
    String response=null;
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    dos.writeBytes("\r\n\r\n");
    mime.writeTo(dos);
    dos.flush();
    dos.close();        
    System.out.println("Connection : "+con);
    String httpCode = String.valueOf(con.getResponseCode()); // I am getting exception here..
    String respMsg = con.getResponseMessage();
    response = "HTTP/1.1 "+httpCode+" "+respMsg+"\n";

    int length = con.getContentLength();
    byte[] cnt = new byte[length];
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(con.getInputStream());
    in.readFully(cnt);
    response = response + new String(cnt).replaceAll("&lt;","<").replace("&gt;",">") + "\n";

    con.disconnect();
    return response;
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        String url = args[0];
        MIMESender sender = new MIMESender(url,"CP001","CP001","CP001");
        File file = new File(args[1]);
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        int len = (int)file.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len];
        in.read(data);

        int n = args.length - 3;
        File[] files = new File[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            files[i] = new File(args[3+i]);
        String resp = sender.sendItem(new String(data),args[2],args[2]);
        System.out.println(resp);

    } catch(IOException io){io.printStackTrace();
    } catch(MessagingException msg){msg.printStackTrace();      
    } catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}

public String getDirectory() {
    return directory;
}

public void setDirectory(String directory) {
    this.directory = directory;
}
```

My full stack trace is:-

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
at com.nokia.content.misc.MIMESender.submit(MIMESender.java:218)
at com.nokia.content.misc.MIMESender.send(MIMESender.java:201)
at com.nokia.content.CTUploader.sendSubItem(CTUploader.java:1202)
at com.nokia.content.CTUploader.send(CTUploader.java:800)
at com.nokia.content.CTUploader.send(CTUploader.java:502)
at com.nokia.content.ui.CPA.doSubmission(CPA.java:727)
at com.nokia.content.ui.CPA.submitMenuItemActionPerformed(CPA.java:571)
at com.nokia.content.ui.CPA.access$16(CPA.java:563)
at com.nokia.content.ui.CPA$9.actionPerformed(CPA.java:195)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please help me to resolve this issue guys..
Thank you..

Comment: This will be impossible to troubleshoot until you have a capture of the network traffic.  Use Wireshark to examine what's happening and compare that to what happens when you use the browser instead.  It's possible you're not sending the correct headers or the `User-Agent` header is causing the server to do something different.  But there's no way we could know that or help you find out.

Comment: Why are you writing two blank lines before the POST data?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is extremely unlikely that anyone can determine your problem based on the code alone, I'm answering with suggestions for how to proceed.

Given that it works from a browser but not from your code, the issue is likely to be that your code doesn't send exactly the same transaction as a browser. The most likely difference will be a missing or extra HTTP header, or a difference in the `User-Agent` header causing the server to close the connection.

The simplest way to debug this is to use Wireshark to capture the network traffic and determine what is different between a browser and your code.  If you find there's a material difference and still need help, post another question showing the relevant differences.